# struggling with python installation/ env

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, conda

Its back to the basics question.  I am struggling to get my head around python installation and environment, and must confess I am new to all this.

I have python installed in both my mac and work laptop (windows). It looks like I have multiple versions of python installed.

When I activate my environment ('Pk') and looks for python version I get this

```
(Pk) prasads-imac:Pk prasadkamath$ python -V
Python 3.6.10 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

when I check the project interpretor I see version 3.7 please see the image.  So looks like I got multiple python installed. But question is what version is my project actually using? 3.6.10 or 3.7. And assuming its using 3.6.10 how do I get it to use 3.7?

[image]

appreciate any help here!

Comment: _But question is what version is my project actually using? 3.6.10 or 3.7._ What do you think? _And assuming its using 3.6.10 how do I get it to use 3.7?_ Take a look at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html.

Comment: thanks @AMC, still not quite if I understood tbh.

Comment: _still not quite if I understood tbh._ Understood what?

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at what path your interpreter is using to run python scripts in settings.
And you may be able to change it somewhere near the terminal area od your interpreter.

Comment: Didnt get that unfortunately. I would have thought that path would be what you see in the attachment i.e. /anaconda2/envs/Pk/bon/python ??